# How to mount a hard disk in Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, playonlinux

How to mount my external hard disk in linux in Ubuntu. as the hard drive is not visible.and the mount option is invisible in hard disk, how I can make it visible and use it.

Comment: attach the drive and run `lsblk` in terminal, edit the question and add the output of this command.

Comment: By default external USB hard disks mount automatically when connected in Ubuntu. Your disk may be faulty.

Comment: My pandrive is visible ,so there is no issue of disk to be faulty.

Comment: Why is this tagged with playonlinux? If your question is related to wine you need to include that in the question as it makes it a different answer.